# listing dynamic content from a json array to listview

Tags: android, json, listview

my situation is the following:
I get a JSON-Array as response from a php script on a server after I sent a hash to it. There are two possible formations of the JSON-Array. If the hash is not valid, the first would be just like `{"status":0}`. Second formation, when the hash is valid, it would have appointments in it -> would be like `{"appointmentName":"Meeting","date":"2013-03-15","startTime":"10:00:00","endTime":"12:10:00","status":2}`.

The JSON-Array could be filled with more than just one appointment.
See below:

```
{
    "appointmentName": "Proposal",
    "date": "2013-11-11",
    "startTime": "09:00:00",
    "endTime": "13:00:00",
    "status": 2
}
{
    "appointmentName": "Meeting",
    "date": "2013-03-15",
    "startTime": "10:00:00",
    "endTime": "12:10:00",
    "status": 2
}
```

I want to list those appointments in a ListView on the android-app.

My method that handles the the JSON-Array:

```
public void handleActivationResult(String result) {     
    try {           
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new String(result));         
            String statusCode = jsonObject.getString("status");

            TextView mainView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            if (statusCode.equals("2")) {
                    //fill listview with appointments
            } else if (statusCode.equals(0)) {
                //empty string sent to server
            } else if (statusCode.equals(5)) {
                //hash doesnt match
            } else if (statusCode.equals(6)) {
                //correct hash, but no upcoming appointments
            } else {
                //unknown error
            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My ListView isnt something special yet:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/appointmentsList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

How should it bee, that the handleActivationResult() method will fill the list with the appointments?

Comment: JSON array for multiple appointments is not valid. check it using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Also, to populate ListView with JSON, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8113337/782609

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I'm trying out the JSONAdapter but the problem here is now, that I dont know how to use it specifically in my Situation on my JSONObject. So the other Part, do I have to change the output of the appointments from my php script?

Comment: look this example-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540754/add-dynamically-elements-to-a-listview-android

Comment: and to handle json array, see this example-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127373/create-android-layout-with-buttons-from-server-response/15128543#15128543

Answer (score 0):

Check the json string consists `"status":0`,if not set the data to the adapter.

When you get response from server,before creating json object check for the string.wheather it contains `"status" 0"` if contains display error string.As you did not mention status for success response in json.

if you are getting `"success":2` then before parsing actual data ,parse status and act accordingly.